# Sails.js / WaterLine insert data into MSSQL database

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm having an issue with inserting data from a formular into a Microsoft SQL database table. It might not be relevant, but just for clarification: these are time tracking entries and they should be added to MS NAV.

My model is pretty simple:

```
module.exports = {

  connection: 'NavMsSql',
  tableName: 'Timestamp',

  attributes: {

  }
};
```

I haven't exactly set the scheme from the table. Most of the attributes have standard datatypes. However, there is a field called `timestamp` which has also the type `timestamp`.

Here is my code for inserting data (simplified):

```
Timestamp.create({
        "timestamp": null,
        "ID": null,
        "Projekt": req.body.project,
        "Task": req.body.task,
        "Datum": entryDate,
        "Zeit": time,
        "Erstellt am": currentDate,
      }).exec(function (err, records) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err.toString());
        }
      });
```

First, when I try to insert this into a mongodb there is absolutely no problem. Everything works as expected.

Trying this with the MSSQL table will result in `RequestError: Invalid column name 'updatedAt'`. 
There is no field which is exactly called `updatedAt`, however, translated into German (which is the language of the table) this would be `Erstellt am` - this field does exist. The attribute's data type is `datetime`.

What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waterline automatically creates updatedAt and createdAt columns at model level and gives values to them accordingly. You need to create these columns in table. 
Or you can disable the automatic creation of these timestamps.

```
autoCreatedAt: false
autoUpdatedAt: false
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for asking dumb, but where (in which file) do I set this parameters to false? Or ist this an optional parameter for the `create` function?

Comment: Its in model, You can check here - http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings

Comment: I think it did. I just tried if works. The issue seems to be resolved. I am receiving now the error `message: 'Incorrect syntax near \')\'.',`. I guess I have to figure the next thing out ;-)